# Is there a way to think of expectation as conditional expectation? If yes, what is the conditioning sigma algebra?

Tags: probability

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ and a random variable X, is any of the following correct? If not, what is the correct conditioning sigma algebra?
$$E[X] = E[X|F]\ where \  F = \{\phi, \Omega\}$$
$$E[X] = E[X|\Omega]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Note that the only $F$-measurable functions are constant functions, so $E[X|F]$ is constant almost surely. Since $E[E[X|F]]=E[X]$, it follows that $E[X|F]=E[X]$ almost surely.

We also have $E[X|\Omega]=E[X]$ since $\sigma(\Omega)=F$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sigma(\Omega) = F$?

Comment: The $\sigma$-field generated by $\Omega$. That is how conditional expectation with respect to a set is defined.

Comment: I dont quite following the last line in your answer. If $E[X|\Omega]=E[X]$, then wouldnt we have $E[X|\Omega]=E[X|F]$?

Comment: $\Omega$ is not a sigma algebra... how do you define conditional expectation w.r.t. $\Omega$? @user1559897

Comment: @ClementC. What is the definition then? I am reading the material on my own and am quite new to this measure theoretic language.

Comment: I may be wrong (it's a bit far), but if I recall correctly you can condition on a $\sigma$-algebra (here, $\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset,\Omega)$) or on a random variable $X$ (which amounts to conditioning on the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(X)$). Conditioning on a single set is not really defined...

Comment: Right! Thanks @McFry

Comment: @ClementC. For a measurable set $A$, $E[X|A] = E[X\cdot\chi_A]/P(A)$. Clearly $E[X|\Omega] = E[X]$.

Comment: Erm. I am not 100% sure, so take this with a grain of salt, but aren't you mixing here the "classical" and the measure-theoretic definitions, picking a bit of each? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event

Comment: If you want it to look like one of the given measure-theoretic definitions, how about this definition: $E[X|A] = E[X|~\chi_A = 1]$ It's the same thing really.

Comment: @McFry Sorry, still fail to see it. Again, may just be me, but you're still conditioning on an event, not a random variable nor a $\sigma$-algebra. I guess it boils down to how you define things, but I don't see exactly how you claim this falls under the measure-theoretic definition. (By the way, I am really not 100% certain about what I say, the "may just be me" is sincere.)

Comment: Typically, conditioning on an event, collection of events or random variable is understood to mean conditioning on the $\sigma$-field generated by it.

Comment: @Jason I would understand that, even though I haven't seen it used. But that's definitely not consistent what the stream of comments above says (e.g., with regard to conditioning on $\emptyset$).

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct: if $\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ then $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]=\mathbb{E}[X]$. This is because the only $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variables are the constant random variables.